# Backbone.js: Collection's "change" event isn't firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a pretty simple collection, but I can't seem to bind to it's change event. In Chrome's console, I'm running:

```
var c = new AwesomeCollection();
c.bind("change", function(){
  console.log('Collection has changed.');
});

c.add({testModel: "Test"}); // Shouldn't this trigger the above log statement?
```

Since this is one of those things that can be difficult to track down, I doubt anybody knows off the top of their head what's going on (if so, great!). So, I'm asking two questions:

1. Should the above code work as anticipated?
2. If so, do you have any suggestions on how to track down where this would fail?

Thanks

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `change` event is only fired when one of the collections' models are modified. When a model is added to the collection the `add` event is fired.
See Backbone.js' [Collection Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection):

> You can to bind "change" events to be notified when any model in the
>   collection has been modified, listen for "add" and "remove"
>   events[...]

To listen for when an `add` occurs modify your code to be

```
var c = new AwesomeCollection();
c.bind("add", function(){
  console.log('Collection has changed.');
});

c.add({testModel: "Test"});
```

Comment: Changing the binding from "change" to "add" still doesn't produce this. Hmmm... the problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: Don't forget too that you can bind multiple events, for example: `c.bind("add remove update", function() {});`

Answer (score 11):

No, that only raises the "add" event.  It will raise the change event if you do this:

```
var c = new AwesomeCollection();
c.bind("change", function() {
  console.log('Collection has changed.');
});

var model = new Backbone.Model({testModel: "Test"});
c.add(model);
model.set({testModel: "ChangedTest"});
```

Comment: You have a missing ")" on the c.bind call.

Comment: So, when a model within the collection is changed

Answer (score 11):

If you want to know when something of significance has been done with a collection, these are the events you probably want to listen to: `change add remove reset`

With respect to your example, this is what your code might look like:

```
var c = new AwesomeCollection();
c.bind('change add remove reset', function(){
    console.log('Collection has changed.');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It may not be necessary in most cases, but you can manually trigger a change event on your object/collection:

```
object.trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't find it documented anywhere but the "all" event fires on all actions, including add, remove and change.

```
var c = new AwesomeCollection();
c.bind("all", function(){
  console.log('Something happened');
});

c.add({testModel: "Test"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope AwesomeCollection is a BackboneCollection.

```
var AwesomeCollection = new Backbone.Collection();

AwesomeCollection.bind('add', function() {
    console.log('new object in the collection');
});

AwesomeCollection.add({something});
```

This should fire your event. If not, there is another problem somewhere else.

Edit: change can't be fired on add event like others said.

Answer (score 0):

Also, we cannot tell from your example, but a Collection must have its model property defined if you want to add models to it by simply passing an object. Otherwise, you must pass a model instance to add().

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as yours on backbone 0.5.3.

Looking at Backbone.Collection.reset() implementation (which is called after a fetch() if you don't provide any "add" optional property), line 503 to 511 :

```
// When you have more items than you want to add or remove individually,
// you can reset the entire set with a new list of models, without firing
// any `added` or `removed` events. Fires `reset` when finished.
reset : function(models, options) {
  models  || (models = []);
  options || (options = {});
  this.each(this._removeReference);
  this._reset();
  this.add(models, {silent: true});
  if (!options.silent) this.trigger('reset', this, options);
  return this;
},
```

2 things are important here :

```
  this.add(models, {silent: true});
```

which means you won't have any "add" event triggered.

Second thing is the :

```
  if (!options.silent) this.trigger('reset', this, options);
```

Meaning that if you replace your code with :

```
var c = new AwesomeCollection();
c.bind("reset", function(){
  console.log('Collection has changed.');
}

c.add({testModel: "Test"}); // Shouldn't this trigger the above log statement?
```

It should work (worked for me)