# backbone .bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this)) not registering

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a `measure` model, that is made up of two collections, a `beats` collections, and a `measureRep`[resentation] collection.  Each collection is made of `beat` models and `representation` models respectively.

Whenever a `measureRep`[resentation] collection changes (by addition or subtraction of a `representation` model), I want the `measureView` (which has the `measure` model, and therefore the `measureRep`[resentation] collection) to re-render itself using the render function().

I am adding a new model in another View by the following function:

```
var representationModel = new RepresentationModel({representationType: newRepType});
StageCollection.get(cid).get('measures').models[0].get('measureRepresentations').add(representationModel);
```

I can see that before and after the addition that the `measure` and its `measureRep` collection are getting added correctly, however, the bind call on the `measureView` is not registering the change and calling the render function.  I even put the bind on the model, to show that the backend is getting updated, however, it doesn't respond.  This leads me to believe that the View and the models are decoupled, but that doesn't make sense, since it originally renders from the model. Here are the relevant files:

measureView.js [View]:

```
define([...], function(...){
  return Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(options){
      if (options) {
        for (var key in options) {
          this[key] = options[key];
        }
        this.el = '#measure-container-'+options.parent.cid;
      }

      window.css = this.collectionOfRepresentations; //I use these to attach it to the window to verify that the are getting updated correctly
      window.csd = this.model;  // Same
      _.bindAll(this, 'render'); // I have optionally included this and it hasn't helped
      this.collectionOfRepresentations.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));

      this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
      // Make a template for the measure and append the MeasureTemplate
      var measureTemplateParameters = { ... };
      var compiledMeasureTemplate = _.template( MeasureTemplate, measureTemplateParameters );
      // If we are adding a rep, clear the current reps, then add the template
      $(this.el).html('');

      $(this.el).append( compiledMeasureTemplate )

      // for each rep in the measuresCollection
      _.each(this.collectionOfRepresentations.models, function(rep, repIndex) {
        var measureRepViewParamaters = { ... };
        new MeasureRepView(measureRepViewParamaters);
      }, this);

      return this;
    },
    ...
  });
});
```

measure.js [Model]:

```
define([ ... ], function(_, Backbone, BeatsCollection, RepresentationsCollection) {
  var MeasureModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      beats: BeatsCollection,
      measureRepresentations: RepresentationsCollection
    },
    initialize: function(){
      var logg = function() { console.log('changed'); };
      this.measureRepresentations.bind('change', logg);
      this.bind('change', logg);
    }
  });
  return MeasureModel;
});
```

representations.js [Collection]:

```
define([ ... ], function($, _, Backbone, RepresentationModel){
  var RepresentationsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: RepresentationModel,
    initialize: function(){
    }
  });

  return RepresentationsCollection;
});
```

I have also tried registering the bind on the `measure` model, and not its child collection, but neither work.

```
_.bindAll(this, 'render');
this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
```

Comment: Could you simplify your test case? As is, it's very hard to follow. Here's a (working) Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/Y2apJ/ , could you modify it (as little as possible) to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175141/1449799

In order to detect additions of models to a collection, you need to listen for the add event (not the change event, which will fire when a model in the collection is changed http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Events-catalog ).

so try:

```
this.measureRepresentations.bind('add', logg);
```